# java constructor(int) undefined, but I do have

Tags: java

```
public File(int phase2ReadSize) {
    mergeIndex=0;
    loadIndex=0;
    sortedEmployee=new Employee[phase2ReadSize];
    end=false;
    size=0; 
}
```

I have a constructor like this, but when I use

```
File tempFile = new File(size)
```

it says "constructor(int) undefined", change size to string.
But I do have. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure it is referring to your custom `File` object and not `java.io.File`?

Comment: oh! maybe you are right, let me try later.

Comment: @yonik try to avoid using the same name as a `java.` package. It can lead to these kinds of mistakes more in general

Answer (score 1):

you imported the `java.io.File` try to import `your File class`.